# Nuget add content as link

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

Is it possible to add nuget content files to a project as a link from the packages folder. Like it works for assembly references.

The background is that I have several projects which include the same set of files (various types). I don't want these files in project folder and the source control tree.

Currently we use the "add as link" feature in Visual Studio to a common folder.

Comment: In this case, isn't a class library better suited than multiple instance of the same file?*

Comment: @SteveB, in many cases yes. The problem is that not all projects use all of the files and the files has other dependecies. If they are all in a library, each projects inherits all dependencies. It just seems easier to create different nuspec files than dividing the files into different projects.